# What’s the semantic difference between the two sentences?

Tags: meaning

From 'Jane Eyre':

> Bessie **was gone** down to breakfast.

Comparing this with an alternative not from 'Jane Eyre':

> Bessie **had gone** down to breakfast.

What’s the semantic difference between these two sentences?

Comment: @snailplane, The first is from 'Jane Eyre.'

Comment: @Listenever: (A) Authors have artistic licence, (B) books written more than 100 years ago are a bad way to learn modern English and grammar.

Comment: What @Matt said. I do not think repeatedly focussing on relatively unusual literary forms from Victorian novelists is a particularly good way of populating the ELL question list. *"Where's Bessie?" "Oh, she **is** gone to work already"*. I don't think so, not in this day and age.

Comment: Is the form "She is gone to work" not still relatively common in British English?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They mean basically the same, but some might want to argue that the first emphasises the state, while the second emphasises the action.

The use of forms of ‘be’ as an auxiliary verb used with the past participle of ‘go’ has a long and respectable history. It is used, as the Oxford English Dictionary says,

> In intransitive verbs, forming perfect tenses; in later use chiefly
>   with verbs of motion such as *come, go, rise, set, fall, arrive,
>   depart, grow*, etc., expressing a condition or state attained at the
>   time of speaking, rather than the action of reaching it, e.g. ‘the sun
>   is set’, ‘our guests are gone’, ‘Babylon is fallen’, ‘the children are
>   all grown up’. Now largely replaced by *have* following the pattern of
>   transitive verbs.

The use of the past tense of ‘be’ is now less frequent than it was, but it is still found in the present tense in expressions such as ‘She’s gone’ and ‘Those days are gone forever.’